# using the .next() function and add/removeClass() functions on tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

so i am having a REALLY tough time trying to understand how to use the next() method and the addClass and removeClass methods.
what i am trying to do is move a class from one table cell to the next cell in the row.
I only have one line of code so far because i really don't know where to begin, so i have pasted my psudo-code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(classname) //Get element with classname
move the class to the next <td>
remove the class from the current <td>
```

i am 90% sure this can be achieved with .next() and addClass(), removeClass()
but i cant seem to find any helpful information on the correct use
this is my first post and i am currently dealing with post concussion syndrome so brain may not be functioning at full power haha

Comment: `.next()` and `addClass()`, `removeClass() ` are jquery methods, so you are okay with jquery? Please share your markup as well. Also do you want this to happen on any event like click()?

Comment: please  share your code in jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: share the code please

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this by JavaScript with:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.active');

if(el) {
    var nextEl = el.nextElementSibling;
    nextEl.setAttribute('class','active');

    el.setAttribute('class','');
}
```

Here is [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/q50jLrvr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered jQuery?

```
$('className').removeClass('className').next('td').addClass('className');
```

Javascript would be

```
var x = document.getElementByClass("className");
var y = document.getElementByClass("className").nextSibling();
x.className = "";
y.className = "className";
```

Bear in mind that elements that use classes are not necessarily unique, where as using ID *should* be.

Comment: i have nothing against JQuery so i will try both, can you still use class names with "getElementById" though? or do you have to have id tags instead?

Comment: You can use javascript and jQuery together. jQuery is a javascript library. getElementById becomes $('className'). or $('#idName'). I'll correct my post!

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery approach might be:

```
$('.className').eq(0).removeClass('className').next('td').addClass('className');
```

In `$('...')` the argument is a **selector** working like a CSS selector string - therefore we need to put a **dot** before the class name.

The argument for `.removeClass('...')` and `.addClass('...')` on the other hand is the **classname**. It is **not** a **selector** and should not have a **dot**.

In native JS things work a little different.

First we define two methods for adding and removing **specific** classes **without changing** the other ones. (The functions are a customization of a script by Craig Buckler I found here: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-vs-raw-javascript-2-css3-animation/)

```
function addClass(node, class) {
    if ((" " + node.className + " ").indexOf(" "+class+" ") >= 0) {
        node.className += " " + class;
    }
}
function removeClass(node, class) {
    var classNameString = " " + node.className + " ";
    if (classNameString .indexOf(" " + class + " ") >= 0) {
        node.className = classNameString
                .replace(" " + class + " ", " ")
                .trim();
    }    
}
```

Then we have to get the elements we are going to change:

```
var currentElement = document.getElementsByClassName('yourClassName')[0],
    nextElement = currentElement.nextElementSibling;
```

In theory this is great but before we can use our new functions we will need to check if `nextElement` really exists, otherwise the script would fail. Here we also check the tag of `nextElement` (here we use **div** but **td** would work just as well - provided you are navigating through `td` elements).

```
if (nextElement !== null && nextElement !== undefined && nextElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === "div") {
    removeClass(currentElement, 'yourClassName');
    addClassName(nextElement, 'yourClassName');
}
```

The native JS approach is perhaps less flexible but executes faster than the jQuery equivalent. But if you are already loading jQuery our JS approach might be redundant. Also I would recommend looking at some tutorials on the subjects of JS and then perhaps jQuery. Writing code without the basics is arduous and debugging will prove quite frustrating.

I forked @Maxali's fiddle and applied some changes:
https://jsfiddle.net/z1357e4f/